# QGIS connection to PostGIS via SSL

Tags: qgis, ssl, ssl-error

I want to connect from QGIS to a PostGIS cluster via SSL.

I'm able to connect via SSL from PgAdmin4 and psql using the same certificates but not from QGIS.

QGIS throws the error:

> SSL error: certificate verify failed

PSQL (works fine):

```
psql "sslmode=verify-ca sslrootcert=server-ca.pem \
      sslcert=client-cert.pem sslkey=client-key.pem \
      hostaddr=XXXXXX \
      port=5432 \
      user=postgres dbname=postgres"
```

PGAdmin 4 (works fine):

[image]
QGIS configuration (doesn't work):

This is the connection form. I use a PKI stored identify certificate

[image]

I create the PKI stored identify certificate as a PKI PEM/DER Certificate Paths. I provide the path of the client's cert (client-cert.pem) and the client's key (client-key.pem).

[image]

The root certificate is also there:

[image]

Server error log:

```
"[214]: [1-1] db=[unknown],user=[unknown] LOG:  could not accept SSL connection: TLSV1_ALERT_UNKNOWN_CA"
```

It looks the root certificate is not sent

Comment: I feel the issue is that the authority of the cert (root cert) cannot be passed as a file

Answer (score 4):

I've finally figured out where I need to place the root authority. Once I added it works!

[image]