# How do I provide PostgreSQL a Root certificate and a username and password with QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, ssl

I am using QGIS 3.22.0-Białowieża and have a PostgreSQL14 server running on an RHEL 8.4 Azure Linux instance.  I believe I need to provide a username:password as well as a combined root/intermediate pem to connect to my PostgreSQL remote server behind a proxy.  In my hba.conf, I open up the IP address I am trying to connect from with hostssl. In postgresql.conf I have ssl = on and ssl_ca_file and ssl_cert_file combined into a single file containing the server sert and an intermediate cert.

I successfully manage the DB with pgAdmin by combining my root cert and intermediate cert as shown below.  I have no issues connecting to the DB with python or through openlayers and geoserver.

[image]

I cannot find a way to do this with QGIS.  Basic authentication doesn't allow me to specify the combined root/intermediate cert.  As I understand it, PKI Paths authentication is asking for the Client certificate and Client certificate key in the screenshot above, not the root certificate I provide PgAdmin.

If I use basic authentication with verify-ca or verify-full for ssl_mode, I can connect to the db in the QGIS browser and add layers.  However, when I go to the DB Manager and try to connect, I get an "SSL error: certificate verify failed" error.

I've tried adding the root cert as the PKI Paths cert and key using PKI paths authentication as well as all the SSL modes.  Nothing works.

Comment: related; https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/348037/qgis-connection-to-postgis-via-ssl

Comment: Thanks for adding the link Mapperz.  I saw that issue and had added the root cert in the certificate manager.  It seems to work for connecting in the browser, but not the DB Manager.  I've seen other related issues such as this:  https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/30075